# Can I delete the "remove the drive" menu in menu-bar in Catalina?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, catalina

After upgrading my mac to Catalina beta, there is an added icon on the menu bar. It looks like a "remove the drive" button but I don't need it.

Is it possible to remove it from the menu bar? Tapping it only reveals "no drive" menu and I has not been able to find anything relevant on System Preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing icons from the menu bar for several versions of macOS has the same process. Knowing that, I’ll guess you are referring to this eject icon:

[image: Disk Eject Icon]

This is the Disk Eject Icon.

If you hold the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key down while clicking on the icon you should be able to drag it out of the menu bar and it will be gone.

If that ain't it add your image to the question and we'll go from there.

Comment: Great answer and assumption. I’ve edited lightly since that’s the eject for many disks, not just optical. Any reason you didn’t up vote the question? It was certainly worth answering even if it wasn’t super clear.

Comment: Thanks and I just found out that this icon exists from very early, and for some reasons the icon suddenly went back to the menu bar after the upgrade to Catalina. I even forgot there is an universal way to remove the icon from the menu bar as my menu bar hasn’t changed for years!